# Product and Review Schema data

Tags: seo, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I am trying to understand Schema data. My website has a Products page and a Reviews page. Do you know if I can implement enable the rich snippets for Reviews on a different page than the products? Can I 'hide' the reviews on the product pages? I am just trying to figure out the best way to implement.

If I have to redesign the markup for the products page to include the reviews, then that is what I will do

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the documentation does ask for the reviews to be nested inside the item being reviewed.

"Make sure the review or ratings markup refers clearly to a specific product or service as shown in the examples above. Do this by nesting the review or ratings within the markup of another schema.org type — such as schema.org/Book or schema.org/LocalBusiness — or by using that schema.org typed element as a value for the itemReviewed property.

https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/reviews?hl=en&rd=1